# Detect WebView URL React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

i'm using native react to integrate an application with webview, however, i need to release the domain in which my application is running, i just don't know the url in which my webview is used.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';



const app =()=>{

  return(
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <WebView
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={{ 
         
            html: 
            `<html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <title>Document</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class= 'overlay' id="teste"></div>
                
                </body>
            </html>
            `
          }}
        />
        {console.log(WebView)}
    </View>
  )
}

export default app
```